# How to quickly input a large number of strings into a file using Bash

Tags: file, bash

I need to create a bunch of permutations of letters, followed by numbers and place it into a file. I have a bunch of nested for loops, as shown below, and then am echoing it into the file, but this is extremely slow, as in probably an hour or more (I am too lazy to figure how long). How can I do this faster, I think the slow part is that I am opening and closing the file way to many times.

```
for a in {a..z}
do
    for b in {a..z}
    do
        for c in {a..z}
        do
            for i in {1..100}
            do
                echo "$a$b$c$i" >> permutations
            done
        done
    done
done
```

Yes I know Bash is not the best language for this, but it is what I have to use.

Any ideas?

Comment: The minimum change to your original solution is to move `>> permutations` to after the last `done`, which will open the file only once. That said, combinatorial brace expansion as in @Anders Lindahl's answer is of course the most elegant way to go.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bash [brace expansion](http://www.gnu.org/s/bash/manual/bash.html#Brace-Expansion) can do this:

```
echo {a..z}{a..z}{a..z}{1..100} > permutations
```

If you want each permutation on a new line you can add a substitution:

```
echo {a..z}{a..z}{a..z}{1..100} | sed -e "s/\ /\n/g" > permutations
```

Comment: The second one could be shortened to: `printf '%s\n' {a..z}{a..z}{a..z}{1..100}`.

Comment: Works great, it only took about five seconds, a vast improvement.